# Backbone request sending to REST API using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, backbone.js

I have implemented a REST API using php. I'm using backbone.js to manage a html view. I need to use AJAX to send requests to REST API and manage the view using backbone. but I can't work out where AJAX fits in with this architecture. I'm confused because when I click the submit button the model is updated meaning the the code below does make a request to API and updates the model and view. Why do I need AJAX request, and where does it fit in, I can't get my head around it even though I have looked at different articles and examples. If I use AJAX what is the point of this line `var urlstr = "API" + this.get("brand");`

```
    var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        var urlstr = "API" + this.get("brand");
        return urlstr;
    },
    defaults: {
        brand: null,
        imageurl: null,
        year: null
    }
});

var bmw = new Car();

var TestView = Backbone.View.extend( {
        el: ".container",
        model: bmw,
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model,"sync change", this.gotdata);
        },
        events: {
            "click #submitbtn" : "getdata"
        },

        getdata: function (event) {
            var brand = $('#brand').val();
            this.model.set({name:brand});
            this.model.fetch();
        },
        gotdata: function () {
            var brand = this.model.get("name");
            var image = this.model.get("imageurl");
            var year = this.model.get("year");
            $('#name').html(name);
            $('#image').html(image);
            $('#year').html(year);
        }
    }
);

var testview = new TestView();
```

Comment: `this.model.fetch()` is an AJAX call that will call your `url` method.

Comment: ahh that clears it. How do I change the request method. for example if I want to send a PUT request where do I state that.

Comment: If you want to use `PUT` for updating a resource using a backbone model, you should use `model.save()`. What happens under the hood is that if the model is set with `id` (the model's idAttribute), it fires an `AJAX` `PUT` request, and if not, it fires `POST`.. [here some docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

Comment: Also you can create any method inside your model and use there `jQuery.ajax()` method

Comment: thanks a lot guys. you're all very helpful.